# illegal forward reference with labels

Tags: java, netbeans, jlabel

I'm having trouble with this...

unlike my last post i have googled and nothing has helped.

Why am i getting the: illegal forward reference error here, and how can i go about fixing it?

```
   public class guihanging extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 int re;
 String [] A = new String[10];
 String word;
 String dash = "";
 int picture = 2;
 String letter = "qw";
 int startOver;
 int qq=0;
 int ww=0;
 int ee=0;
 int rr=0;
 int tt=0;
 int yy=0;
 int uu=0;
 int ii=0;
 int oo=0;
 int pp=0;
 int aa=0;
 int ss=0; 
 int dd=0;
 int ff=0;
 int gg=0;
 int hh=0;
 int jj=0;
 int kk=0;
 int ll=0;
 int zz=0;
 int xx=0;
 int cc=0;
 int vv=0;
 int bb=0;
 int nn=0;
 int mm=0;




public guihanging() {
    initComponents();

    { 
       A[0]="rob";
       A[1]= "welcome";
       A[2]= "carbohydrates";
       A[3]= "resiprocity"; 
       A[4]="fatty";
       A[5]="baggy";
       A[6]="laptop";
       A[7]="personalcomputer";
       A[8]="monitor";
       A[9]="mouse";
     }
}
public void letters()
{System.out.println("");}
{
 int wordleng = word.length();
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < wordleng; i2++) 
    {

      int position = word.indexOf(letter);
      if (position >= 0)
      {
         String before = word.substring(0,position);
         String after = word.substring(position+1);
         word = before + "@" + after; 
         int dashPosition = position * 2;
         String dashBefore = dash.substring(0,dashPosition);
         String dashAfter = dash.substring(dashPosition + 1);
         dash = dashBefore + letter + dashAfter;
         lblWord.setText(dash);//error

      }
      else 
      {
         lblPicture.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pictures/"+picture+".png")));// error
         picture++;
         if (picture == 7)
         {
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Unluck, You just did a burpee!!"+"/n"+"do you want to start again?");

             if (true)
             {
               re = (int) (Math.random ()*10);
               word = "aaabcqdefghiqjklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //A[re];
               for (int i1 = 0; wordleng < 10; i1++) 
                  {
                     dash = dash + "_ ";
                  }
              lblWord.setText(dash);/error
            }

         }
      }

    }
}
```

the errors are all by the labels

EDIT LEFT THIS OUT

```
  private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    re = (int) (Math.random ()*10);
    word = A[re];
    int wordleng = word.length();
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < wordleng; i1++) 
    {
       dash = dash + "_ ";
    }

    lblWord.setText(dash)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Whats the error and from where... and share code for you lblword...

Comment: sorry left that out and thats the only code for lblWord its still in the start of the project.. im a big noob

Answer (score 0):

"Illegal forward reference" means you use a variable which is not defined. Maybe you miss to define your variables: `dash` or `lblWord`?

Comment: how would i define lblWord?

Comment: i dont know which class `lblWord` is, but you have to do a `new <classname> ` before you use this object.

Comment: it works when i put it into public but doesn't work when in public void. also works with a button

Comment: so what is your question now ?

Comment: how would i get it to work? im a student who starteted java 2 months ago and dont know what to do

Comment: the problem is that we dont know your code. How should we say what is wrong without the complete code and error. I dont know where your object `lblWord`is defined, so we cannot help you more than this.

Comment: im getting illegal forwarding reference error i will put all my code in original post

Comment: `String word` is not initialized --> but you use `int wordleng = word.length();` same as your `lolWord`. Dont know what you will do with this variable. Maybe create a Object `lblWord`?

Comment: sry - your code doenst compile. `initComponents()`is not set within this class. Your Objects `lblWord, lblPicture` are not defined, ` lblWord.setText(dash);/error` is not compileable and `word` is still a nullpointer exception. Please. learn to compile your code first.